# On Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula for irrational numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, big-list, big-picture, irrational-numbers

A [BBP-type formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) for an irrational number $\alpha$ in the integer base $b\geq 2$ is a formula in the form $\alpha=\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{b^k}\frac{p(k)}{q(k)}$ ($p, q$ are polynomials in integer coefficients) that allows computing the $n$th digit of $\alpha$ in the basis $b$ directly and without any need to computing the preceding $n-1$ digits of $\alpha$. It is also connected to the problem of normality of irrational numbers.

1- For which irrational numbers do we have a known Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula? For which of them do we have such a formula in the base $10$? (Please add a reference to a list if there is any).

2- Is there any known BBP formula for $e$ in an integer base $b$?

3- For which irrational numbers, the normality of the number in a given base is proved using a BBP formula?

Answer (score 4):

Concerning (1), there is a large compendium of BBP formulas in this [paper](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/bbp-formulas.pdf) by Bailey. Regarding (2), it is strongly suspected (but not proved) that there is no BBP formula for $e$.  Here is a quote from the paper by Bailey.

> Powers of $e$ are specified here because, as far as anyone can tell (although this has not
>   been rigorously proven), $e$ is not a polylogarithmic constant in the sense of this paper,
>   and thus it and its powers are not expected to satisfy BBP-type linear relations (this
>   assumption is confirmed by extensive experience using the author’s PSLQ programs).