# Is there a Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe (BBP) formula for $\gamma$ (euler-mascheroni constant)?

Tags: algorithms, computational-number-theory

I was reading about BBP type formulas and there was a lot about $\pi$ and some $\log$'s. I started searching for some other constants and could find $2$ formulas for the catalan constant and learned that there is no formula for $e$. I want to know if there is a BBP type formula for $\gamma=0.577...$ but couldn't find anything about it. Such formula exists?

Comment: “there is no formula for e” Source?

Comment: @user76284 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219816/on-bailey-borwein-plouffe-formula-for-irrational-numbers

Comment: I believe that says suspected, not proven.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If "having a BBP-type formula for $\alpha\in\mathbb R$" is defined as "there is $r\in\mathbb Q(x)$ and $b\in\mathbb R_{\mathrm{alg}}$ (the field of real $\mathbb Q$-algebraic numbers) such that $\alpha=\sum_{n\ge0}b^{-n}r(n)$", it seems that the answer is either "no" or inaccesible. For this definition, it's easy to see using fractional decomposition and some manipulations with power series, that if $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ has a BBP-type formula, then it's a Kontsevich--Zagier period (i.e. is expressible in a form $\int_Sq(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\,dx_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_k$ for some $\mathbb R_{\mathrm{alg}}$-[semialgebraic set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semialgebraic_set) $S\in\mathbb R^k$,  and $q\in\mathbb R_{\mathrm{alg}}(x)$). But it is currently not known whether $\gamma$ is a KZ-period. By the way, there are strong suspects that it isn't (in particular, it seems that there is no BBP-type formula for $\gamma$)